# Flutter how to combine two lists of maps with different lengths by matching keys in both maps

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am retrieving data from my database in my app using queries and the result is I have two sets of lists. The first list is details from the first query which returns user details and bank information. The second list is from the second query which returns a user order information.

Here is data from the first query

```
[{
    name: User 1,
    msisdn: +2540700222333,
    userID: 15e15701,
    bank_accountsId: null,
    accountsId: 15e15700,
    accountBalance: 0.0,
    accountCredit: 0.0,
    accountDebit: 0.0
}, {
    name: User 2,
    msisdn: +254712345678,
    userID: cb0033b0,
    bank_accountsId: null,
    accountsId: c3ddf800,
    accountBalance: 0.0,
    accountCredit: 0.0,
    accountDebit: 0.0
}]
```

This is data from the second query

```
[{
    ordersID: 091848,
    userID: cb0033b0,
    orderItemsID: 091896,
    productUnitID: 12,
    productID: 5,
    inventory: 30.0,
    skus: 1
}]
```

I want to combine data from the two lists and where the userID does not exists I pass null to the corresponding fields/keys to look like the one below

```
[{
    name: User 1,
    msisdn: +2540700222333,
    userID: 15e15701,
    bank_accountsId: null,
    accountsId: 15e15700,
    accountBalance: 0.0,
    accountCredit: 0.0,
    accountDebit: 0.0,
    ordersID: null,
    orderItemsID: null,
    productUnitID: null,
    productID: null,
    inventory: null,
    skus: null

}, {
    name: User 2,
    msisdn: +254712345678,
    userID: cb0033b0,
    bank_accountsId: null,
    accountsId: c3ddf800,
    accountBalance: 0.0,
    accountCredit: 0.0,
    accountDebit: 0.0,
    ordersID: 091848,
    orderItemsID: 091896,
    productUnitID: 12,
    productID: 5,
    inventory: 30.0,
    skus: 1
}]
```

Comment: i didnt find any userID there?

Comment: @pmatatias I have updated to show userID